# SignatureDoesNotMatch Error S3 Presigned URL

Tags: python, ajax, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using `generate_presigned_post()` function to generate a presigned url using a lambda, it is as follows:

```
response= s3_client.generate_presigned_post(
        Bucket = bucket_name,
        Key = key,
        ExpiresIn = 30
      )
```

The response is in the format:

```
{
  "signed_url": {
    "url": "xxx",
    "fields": {
      "key": "xxx",
      "x-amz-algorithm": "xxx",
      "x-amz-credential": "xxx",
      "x-amz-date": "xxx",
      "x-amz-security-token": "xxx",
      "x-amz-signature": "xxx"
    }
  }
}
```

In the client side i'm using the following code to upload an image:

```
 function uploadToS3(data){
    var form = new FormData();
    var url  = JSON.parse(data["signed_url"])["url"]
    var fields = JSON.parse(data["signed_url"])["fields"]

    var presigned_url = url + fields.key + "?" +
    "X-Amz-Algorithm=" + fields["x-amz-algorithm"] +
    "&X-Amz-Credential=" + fields["x-amz-credential"] +
    "&X-Amz-Date=" + fields["x-amz-date"] +
    "&X-Amz-Expires=30"+
    "&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"+
    "&X-Amz-Security-Token=" + encodeURIComponent(fields["x-amz-security-token"]) +
    // "&policy="+ fields["policy"]
    "&X-Amz-Signature=" + fields["x-amz-signature"];


    form.append("file", $('#customFile1').get()[0].files[0], data['signed_url']['fields']['key']);

    // for (var pair of form.entries()) {
    // console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
    // }
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url: presigned_url,
        data: form,
        // timeout:0,
        processData:false,
        // mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        success:function(resp){
            console.log(resp)
        },
        fail:function(resp){
            console.log(resp)
        },
        error:function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
    }
    })
    }
```

I'm getting this error, The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function uploadToS3(data){
    var form = new FormData();
    var url  = JSON.parse(data["signed_url"])["url"]
    var fields = JSON.parse(data["signed_url"])["fields"]

    for (const k in fields) {
      const v = fields[k];
      formData.set(k, v);
    }

    formData.set("file", $('#customFile1').get()[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: form,
        // timeout:0,
        processData:false,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        success:function(resp){
            console.log(resp)
        },
        fail:function(resp){
            console.log(resp)
        },
        error:function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
    }
    })
    }
```